# Dual H-bridge DC motor driver using logic voltage supply and not actual voltage supply

Tags: arduino, pwm, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller, h-bridge

I am trying to control two 12V motors with this [H-bridge board](https://www.dfrobot.com/product-1861.html) using a 12 V 7 Ah battery and an Arduino Uno.

What I have noticed is that my PWM signals are acting as on/off, and the motors are receiving the same voltage as the VCC logic pins on the driver board, not the actual voltage supply we have connected.

When PWM is set 0-127 the motors are off, from 128-255 the motors run at 5 V - if the VCC logic on the driver board is connected to a 5 V pin on the Arduino, or run at 3.3 V if logic is on 3.3 V Arduino pin.

We have the 12 V battery hooked up, it just seems the H-bridges are ignoring PWM and our 12 V supply.

I also have a buck converter I hooked up to the driver board VCC pins, and the motor speed changes based on how much voltage I give it. I’ve pushed it up to 5.5 V and I can see that is what the motors are receiving, not the 12 V we have supplied.

What is wrong here? Should I just use the standard L298N drivers instead?
Could I be limited by current somehow?

Comment: Yes, try L298N and let us know if there is any difference.

Comment: 1.  Show your circuit diagram. 2. Do you have the grounds properly connected between the Arduino, the controller board, and the battery?

Comment: No, do NOT just randomly replace things.  If you've wired the current module incorrectly then you'll likely do the same with the L298N.  Find out what is wrong first.

Comment: We can't possibly tell you what's wrong if you don't first tell us what you have done. We need schematics showing how you have hooked together the Uno, driver and motor.